# Flutter textformfield controller display issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to store the key value in the textformfield while displaying the description to the user for the same textformfield. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: Can you give more details about what you want to accomplish? What `description` are you referring to? What kind of "key value" do you want to store? Maybe give us a simple example to make your question more clear.

Comment: I have a textformfield with a dropdown look. The dropdown list(CupertinoPicker) is loading data from a database with key and description listed. When an entry is selected, I would like to store the key in the textformfield while displaying the description to the user in the same field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `controller` property to display the description to the user in a TextFormField.

```
TextFormField(
  controller: TextEditingController(text: dataFromFirebase[description]),
)
```

To handle the storing of the key value, you can use the `onSelectedItemChanged` property of the CupertinoPicker. This way, you can write a function (that stores the selected item's key/data) that runs when the user selects an item from the dropdown.

Comment: Yes, this worked.